# unique types and decidability

Tags: reference-request, model-theory, decidability

Suppose $\mathcal{M}$ is an infinite structure which has the property that every type that is realised is realised uniquely. Also assume that every element of $\mathcal{M}$ is definable but there is no single constant bounding the quantifier depth of the defining formulae.

Q1)When does $Th(\mathcal{M})$ admit quantifier elimination?

Q2) When is $Th(\mathcal{M})$ decidable?

Comment: Hi, regarding "every element of $\mathcal{M}$ is definable but there is no single constant bounding the quantifier depth of the defining formulae" -- do you have an example of such an $\mathcal M$"?

Comment: How about a pointwise definable model of ZFC?  (http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?verb=Display&version=1.0&service=UI&handle=euclid.jsl/1358951104&page=record)

Comment: That's good, how about a decidable example...

Comment: Not sure this works, but: how about a disjoint union of a bunch of finite graphs $G_n$ (with each $G_n$ "attached" to an element of a disjoint copy of $\mathbb{N}$, just so we effectively have predicates for each $G_n$), where each $G_n$ has every element definable in at most $n$ many quantifiers? Something like that might have a decent chance of being decidable, if the $G_n$s are chosen carefully.

Comment: The second assumption implies the first one, or am I missing something?

Comment: Effective QE implies decidability. Is it known that they are equivalent? Cant we have decidability without QE?

Comment: I mean: if every element of $\mathcal M$ is definable, then so is every tuple, hence in particular any two distinct tuples realize distinct complete types.

Comment: Come think of it, “there is no single constant bounding the quantifier depth of the defining formulae” trivially implies that there is no bound on the complexity of formulas up to equivalence in $\mathrm{Th}(\mathcal M)$, hence the answer to Q1 is *never*.